# Stapling In Postscript File on Ricoh or Keyoceria Or Toshiba Printers

Tags: printing, postscript, printers

I am writing a postscript file through coding in VB.net and pslibrary. My Main purpose for the job is tray switching from 3 different trays and having stapled the sets based on variable input. i.e I have a post script file of 100 pages first two pages will be simplex and will be printed from two different trays. On third page we will use the third tray and pages from third tray to onward 10 pages will be stapled. After page eleven to next 8 pages will be stapled separately. So it will go so on.

Note: Ricoh Aficio/ Gestatner/ Toshiba Printers is in use 2105-2090 models are being in used.

1. Tray switching and file is working fine except stapling
2. Stapling is not working through PS although working fine on machine separately.

Following code is being used to do the work

```
    **{{{
     %%Page: 3 3
    %%BeginPageSetup
    << /PageSize[595 841] /Duplex false /MediaColor (Red) /Jog 3 /Staple 3 /StapleDetails << /Type 1 /StapleLocation (SinglePortrait) >>>>  setpagedevice
    save
    %%EndPageSetup
(InvoiceNo 50011287697) 72 755.28 /ArialMT 15 SF
%EndPage: 3
restore
showpage
<</PageSize [595 842]/MediaType (Red) /MediaColor (Red) /MediaWeight 75/Duplex false>> setpagedevice
%%Page: 4 4
%%BeginPageSetup
save
%%EndPageSetup
(InvoiceNo 50011287697) 72 755.28 /ArialMT 15 SF
%EndPage: 4
restore
showpage
<< /Jog 0 >>  setpagedevice
<< /Staple 0 >>  setpagedevice
}}}**
```

But no stapling is done and printing is started to get out from first paper and that too through its finisher. Printer is just ignoring Staple commands

Answer (score 1):

Things like tray selection and stapling are printer specific. You'll need to extract appropriate code fragments from the .PPD files for the printers in question.

Depending on the exact code fragments needed, it may be possible to combine the fragments into a single PostScript fragment that will work on all of these printers. But it's unlikely to make a fully general solution.

For example, the [Ricoh Afficio 2105 PPD file](http://www.openprinting.org/download/PPD/Ricoh/PS/Ricoh-Aficio_2105_PS.ppd) has fragments like this:

```
<< 
  /Collate true  /CollateDetails <</Type 6 /AlignSet true>>
  /Staple 2  /StapleDetails << /Type 14 /Angle 0 /Position 0 >>
>> setpagedevice
```

The `Position` changes for different locations but is always a small integer for this printer.

[Gestetner 2212](https://www.openprinting.org/ppd-o-matic.php?driver=Postscript-Gestetner&printer=Gestetner-2212&show=1) shows fragments that look the same to me as for the Ricoh.

The fragment for a [Toshiba 2500C](https://www.openprinting.org/ppd-o-matic.php?driver=Postscript-Toshiba&printer=Toshiba-e-Studio_2500c&show=1) is completely different:

```
    <</TSBPrivate (DSSC PRINT STAPLING=769) >> setpagedevice
```

Comment: I have the PPD file but it is still not workable can you look at it

Comment: I looked at a few different PPD files. It looks like Gestetner printers are manufactured by Ricoh so they actually use the same PostScript (for the models I looked at), but the code for a Toshiba is completely different. <answer edited to include examples>

Comment: Thank you @luser droog I have implemented the same but stapling is done on whole file consisting of multiple invoices. whereas i am looking to staple the multiple invoices separately in single file.

Comment: I'm afraid I just don't know how to do that or if it's even possible. So I asked for help in [comp.lang.postscript](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.postscript/33E7hdYvrT8/discussion). Hopefully someone there will know more.

Comment: @Ahmad It seems like the best way to do this is to separate each invoice into its own document.